# Using angular.forEach() and Array.prototype.forEach() in angular application

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach

I am developing angular application, in which I used `angular.forEach` method to iterate over arrays *(Not over objects)*. It is working similar as `Array.prototype.forEach`. So I am having some questions about using this.

1. Which method is good for use as per standards.
2. Which is good as per performance. I tested on [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/angularjs-foreach-vs-native-foreach/5), It gave same result.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that Angular's `forEach` will delegate to `Array.prototype.forEach` if it's  available.

Comment: angular.forEach is pretty much the same as Array.prototype.forEach or jQuery.forEach. It is just wrapping functionality. So it does was a library has to do actually (making the developers life easier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [angular.forEach-Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach), it does prevent `TypeError(s)`.

> Unlike ES262's Array.prototype.forEach, Providing 'undefined' or 'null' values for obj will not throw a TypeError, but rather just return the value provided.

So it pretty much does was a Library always does. It wraps up some functionality, like checking for null, undefined etc. and handles those occurences, so the developer hasn't to deal with it.

If you want to handle those `TypeError`s yourself go with `Array.prototype.forEach` otherwise use the Library functions.

It won't differ Performance wise.